# Customize the standard contact details Web Part

Tags: web-part, contacts

The standard contact details Web Part of SharePoint 2013 is only showing the name of a person and - when available - the picture of this person.

Is there any way to add details to this form ("caught" by the users profile (SP) / Active Directory), such as phone number and E-Mail address?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Unfortunately NO**

It is pre-defined SharePoint webpart in environment. You have to create custom webpart to get all the details for specific user from SharePoint users profile OR Active Directory.