# Change source for presence indicator

Tags: 2013, web-part, microsoft-teams, classic-experience, presence-indication

We are using SharePoint 2013 and Skype for Business.

Normally the contact details web part in SharePoint displays the Skype presence details (Online, Busy,...).

Is there any way to change this web part's "*presence source*" from Skype to MS Teams?

What I have found so far all deals with creating a separate web part for it which in our case wouldn't really be an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there are any default web part settings to change the "Presence Source".

Also, you cannot customize the SharePoint default web part to change the "Presence Source".

**Similar thread**:

1. [Customize the standard contact details Web Part](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/180206/customize-the-standard-contact-details-web-part)

Comment: What i suspected. Thanks for the quick reply.